# Does Google calendar import vtodo in ics format?

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

I am trying to import a vtodo (task in ics format) in google calendar

```
BEGIN:VTODO
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
BEGIN:VTASK
DTSTART:20120731T000000
DUE:20120731T000000
SUMMARY:test
ORGANIZER:CN=xxx@xxx.com
ATTENDEE:CN=xxx@xxx.com
PERCENT-COMPLETE:0
STATUS:0
PRIORITY:1
CATEGORIES:General
DESCRIPTION:
END:VTASK
END:VTODO
```

it says invalid ics file. can google calendar only import vevents ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Google Calendar will only import events from ICS files. But your ICS file is also invalid.

It needs to be surrounded with `VCALENDAR` BEGIN and END tags, and `VTASK` is not a valid marker in the format (it is not mentioned in [the speciifcation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5546)).